# fnPageChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, fnpagechange

I am getting the subject error when using the following:

```
 $("#example1").DataTable().fnPageChange(localStorage.getItem('page'),true);
```

From what I understand, it saves the last page of the datatable that the user clicked on.  If the user has clicked on the 3rd page of the datatable, navigates to another page and then goes back to the datatable, it will still be on the 3rd page of the datatable.

And it works.  The last page of the datatable is saved.

The only problem is, even though the above works, I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).fnPageChange is not a function
```

I am not sure why.

Here are some other datatable setting I have:

```
"iDisplayLength": 50,
"order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
"paging": true,
"scrollY": 300,
"scrollX": true,
"bDestroy": true,
"stateSave": true,
"sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
"autoWidth": false,
"deferRender": true,
"dom": 'Bfrtip',
```

Why am I getting the above console error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the [`"stateSave": true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option is what is allowing a user to return to page 3 of the DataTable, after leaving the web page entirely, and then returning.

It also saves filters and sorting selections.

If you want to do something manually, which is not handled for you by `"stateSave": true`, then you can use the DataTables [page change event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page). The documentation gives an example:

```
$('#example').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    var info = table.page.info();
    $('#pageInfo').html( 'Showing page: '+info.page+' of '+info.pages );
} );
```

Otherwise, you can delete that line which is throwing the error - and state saving should not be affected.

---

Regarding `fnPageChange` - this is an old plug-in which has been removed from DataTables - you can see a note about this [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.6#Common-upgrade-issues).

Comment: That's great to know that fnPageChange is no longer being used.  Wish I would've known that earlier.  In regards to the code you suggested, I was unsuccessful getting it to work.  I placed both within the datatable scope as well as outside of the scope.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the code I suggested. You are already using ` "stateSave": true` - and that is all you should need. Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: I was referring to the sample code you provided from https://datatables.net/reference/event/page - side note: the "stateSave" feature does not save the last page for me.

Comment: OK, understood.  You would have to show us exactly how you used that code, and what the specific error message was. For example, the code from the web site assumes your table variable is `example` - whereas in your question, it looks like you are using `example1` instead. That may be why your usage failed - or it may be for some other reason.

Comment: Regarding your note about state saving not working - I cannot explain that! Can you provide a [mre] - maybe in a Fiddle, or similar? That is curious.

Comment: Before I try to create a fiddle, is stateSave supposed to save the most recent page of the datatable?  If so, then maybe something I am doing is preventing stateSave from working.

Comment: Yes - [it is](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) (it stores the pagination position). You can see saved state in your browser dev tools. For FireFox, hit F12, then go to Storage > Local Storage. It's probably similar for other browsers. Doing this is a good way to identify the auto-generated names DataTables uses for storing its state. The key will be something like `DataTables_data_table_blah...` and the value will be a JSON object containing all the table's saved state. There is no value called `page`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable começa com minúsculo é um  camel case.

```
 $("#example1").DataTable().fnPageChange(localStorage.getItem('page'),true);
```

change to

```
$("#example1").dataTable().fnPageChange(localStorage.getItem('page'),true);
```